# Stepping down as a moderator

Tags: discussion

I'm stepping down as a moderator.
StackExchange has developed too many systemic problems.
I don't think that putting time into StackExchange is the right thing for me to do.

Comment: You have performed very well as moderator. Thank you.

Comment: I think you must have also (given that I don't remember getting into a fight with you)!

Comment: As a SE member first, and mainly incidentally as a new moderator second, I'd be very interested in hearing anything you are willing to say about the issues which have affected your desire to continue as moderator. Public or private comment is welcome. (My email address is in my profile).  || I became a moderator in large part to help newcomers gain a foothold and to hopefully help improve answer Q&A quality by addressing areas perhaps less addressed by many. I'm finding a fair bit of time is taken in activity akin to "herding adult cats" :-) :-(.

Comment: Hi Nick, may I ask if [this](https://electrical.codidact.com/users/52935) is you? Do you plan participate here or at Codidact (as a user)?

Comment: @Dmitry  Yes, that's me.  I don't plan to answer questions on SE.  I might answer questions on Codidact.

Comment: Thanks for your work, Nick.

Comment: Bravo for holding the fort as long as you have. Systemic SE issues were the ultimate reason I didn't want to run in the last mod election. See you on the other site, hopefully.

Comment: From me - another very sincere thanks for your time and effort here, Nick.

Comment: Your efforts and time here have always been much appreciated, Nick. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks for all your service, and good luck!